# How to store result of type char in pointer?

Tags: c, pointers

I want to store result of type char in pointer which I'm passing as argument of function. Like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void try(char *);
int main()
{
    char *result;
    try(result);
    printf("%s",result);
    return 0;
}
void try(char *result)
{
    result="try this";
}
```

But I'm getting result : **(null)**

Could someone tell me what's wrong here?

Comment: You are passing `result` by value, meaning that `result` in `main` and `result` in `try` are two different variables (although both points to the same memory location since you've passed it to the function). Altering `result` from `try` doesn't change `result` from `main`. You need to pass the address of `result`(pass by reference) to `try` like the answers below have suggested to get the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also another way (no dynamic memory):

```
#include<stdio.h>
void try(char *);
int main()
{
    char result[100] = {0};
    try(result);
    printf("%s",result);
    return 0;
}
void try(char *result)
{
    strcpy(result,"try this");
}
```

Note: When you say you got null, that doesn't mean anything - actually you had undefined behaviour there  - because `result` was not initialized. I guess you invoked UB even before trying to print `result`, namely when you passed it to `try`. Because copy would be made in that method of the pointer, which would try to read value of original pointer - reading uninitialized variables is undefined in C. Hence always initialize your variables in C.

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax only sends the pointer to the function. This allows changing the data the pointer points to, but not the pointer itself.

You would need to have

```
void try(char **result)
```

and call it

```
try(&result);
```

to change the actual pointer.

Another way is to copy data into the memory pointed by the pointer, but then you need to know there is enough memory available. Depends on the actual use case how to do it properly. You might use

```
strcpy(result, "what you want");
```

but then you *really* have to know that the memory pointed by `result` can handle 14 chars (remember the NULL in the end). In your current code you don't allocate memory at all for result, so this will invoke undefined behaviour.

The reason you're seeing NULL is because your compiler decided to initialize non-assigned pointers to NULL. Another compiler might initialize them to random values.

Also about terminology, you're not storing type char into a pointer. You may have a pointer pointing to a char, or in this case to a C type string, which is an array of chars.

Comment: Is it possible to get result from function with this call of function  `void try(char *result)`

Comment: @Lolipop Clarified that part, but do note that without allocating memory beforehand it is not possible, since you cannot modify where the pointer points.

Comment: I tried to allocate memory and then I used strcpy like this: `void try(char *result)
{
 result = malloc(30);  
 strcpy(result, "try this");
} ` But my result is **null** again.

Comment: @Lolipop As I explained, you have to allocate memory *before* calling this function, since the value of the pointer *cannot be changed* outside the function unless you use `char**`

Answer (score 1):

You are creating another variable `result` inside `try` function.
Try printing `result` inside `try` function. It will work then.

If you really want to print inside `main` then try this -

```
#include<stdio.h>

void try(char **);

int main()
{
    char *result;
    try(&result);
    printf("%s",result);
    return 0;
}
void try(char** result)
{
    *result = "try this";
    //printf("%s\n",result);
}
```

Or if you don't want to get into double pointers, then this will work:

```
#include<stdio.h>

char* try(char *);

int main()
{
    char *result;
    result = try(result);
    printf("%s",result);
    return 0;
}
char* try(char* result)
{
    result = "try this";
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Well I need to work with this call of function `void try(char* result)`